# box-shadow is not recognized

Tags: css, linux, gedit, box-shadow

I have this CSS code for a textbox class and I'm on working on linux.
It's saved in a .css file and i'm using gedit. But the box-shadow property isn't recognized. All the others have that different font which shows a keyword or so. But not box-shadow. Any ideas please? It seems to work on windows when i use notepad++.

```
.textbox 
{ 
    background: white; 
    border: 1px solid #ffa853; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px #00FFFF; 
    color: #666; 
    outline: none; 
    height:23px; 
    width: 275px; 
}
```

Comment: your css work fine in all the browers

Comment: It's supposed to. It's a standard property. but gedit is not recognizing it. 
http://postimg.org/image/6sc3ukwzf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be confusing box-shadow with text-shadow.
text-shadow applies to text, box applies to containers

I have made a small [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aj8ayvdg/) to demonstrate both

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}
p {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
  color: red;
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    hello
  </p>
</div>
```

if you are trying to adjust the appearance of an input (or a number of inputs)
a useful way of doing it is:

```
input[type="text"] {
    /*your styles here*/
}
```

Comment: if you can't see the box shadow on the snippet, or text shadow for that matter,  please add a comment

Comment: also read the 'known issues' in caniuse.com http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow

Comment: no. i am trying to use it for textbox input in a form.
I've added a link to a screenshot of the code. You'll see that box-shadow is the only property not recognized. 
http://postimg.org/image/6sc3ukwzf/

Comment: ok. so i've added screenshots of everything so far.
CSS:  http://postimg.org/image/6sc3ukwzf/
HTML: http://postimg.org/image/4g8fdi6t7/f52e91ab/
Output: http://postimg.org/image/svg6v6osb/

I just cant figure out why gedit wont recognize it. Other editors do.

Comment: for a start, your inputs should be type="text" not class ="text", for another thing there is no sign of your class "textbox", so how do you expect it to find it?

Comment: oh my god. i can't believe i made such a stupid mistake. Thank you so much. 
I kept it as class instead of type because that's the one i knew how to set css for. With the ".textbox".

Comment: i have edited my answer with an easy way to update your inputs. Dont worry, we all make mistakes! :) (an upvote wouldn't go astray tho.. wink wink ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any ideas as to why gedit doesn't recognize the box-shadow tag? It works. But it's annoying to see it like that.

Comment: Is it still like that? It was probably because the class wasn't in use at the time.. It should be OK now..

Comment: Maybe add px after your 0 s, that's all I would suggest